# Why am I getting color bands at high ISOs?

Tags: nikon, iso, artifacts, nikon-d80

I have an old Nikon D80 with me. When I shoot with higher ISO, like 800, vertical color bands are produced in the image.

***Why does it happen and is there any way to eliminate it?***

---

**Example with high ISO** | Image taken at f/29, 1/160, 44.00mm
[image: High ISO Example]

**Example with low ISO** | Note: no color banding.
[image: Low ISO Example]

Comment: You'd have to post more info, and a sample... otherwise we can only guess

Comment: And have a close look at your low iso images as well (especially the darker areas). I'd expect the noise to be there as well, but of course at a lower level.

Comment: No it's not, I'll get noise band even when I shoot at 1/00s 800 iso 4f

Comment: @AthomSfere I'll post it soon

Comment: @AthomSfere link is given

Comment: I don't see what's wrong with the image...? D80 is a 12 years old camera so don't expect perfect results with higher ISO values.

Comment: And why f/29? Do you really need such DoF? With a bit lower f-Number you could also use lower ISO setting.

Comment: That was shot for testing the range, the scene was too bright that's why I use higher f stop, and even when f/4 and iso 800 I get noise

Comment: I wouldn't call the green vertical color banding that I'm seeing noise, per-se. I'm on a severely uncorrected monitor though, so to confirm, that's the effect you're talking about...right?

Comment: @Corey yeah the green color and the palm is not red it's also another band

Comment: Thats what I need to know it's not a normal case and I used to shoot at higher iso and aperture but after a particular time these bands showed up

Comment: @Corey that's it I never seen such an effect in any photos I have made with different models and in extreme settings

Comment: @STAIN You shouldn't ever be shooting at such a high f-stop.  You start to lose clarity around f/15.  Shooting at f/29 means that, while everything might be in focus, you are giving up a significant amount of sharpness.  The color bands are a result of an old camera sensor that doesn't handle high ISO well.

Comment: @HairyDresden does it's sensor got weak due to working at extreme settings

Comment: @STAIN as you turn the ISO up you get more digital interference. This is an example of that.

Comment: @STAIN (don't get me wrong and just to be safe: are the lens and cam clean, not broken or shaky? equipment in not good condition can result in many "funny" effects, like my lose lens element in my old lens) can you provide a series of different ISO settings to see if the effect starts at a certain point or just becomes more worse for higher ISO settings. e.g. a not full daylight scene with some dark and light areas e.g. some LED lights or maybe the TV with a test picture.

Comment: It happen when the iso increases above 640 I guess in lower iso it work perfectly, I'll show a photo that I took with an iso 100

Comment: @Horitsu added one

Comment: Pls provide us multiple iso samples from the same scene where color banding appers good visable. This is to ensure that no other factor than the iso is changing

Comment: Wouldn't the easiest case for this be a white (or mono-colored) wall? ideally not in bright sunlight, as flares might emerge (and to me, the green band in the first image sort of looks like one.)

Comment: @Horitsu I'll send

Comment: @flolilolilo those are not flares, from the shadows it's clear that the sun is behind me.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what I've read, CCD's are prone to producing excess noise with high ISO and long exposure. The effect you are observing may be **blooming or smearing of the CCD.** According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge-coupled_device#Blooming):

> When a CCD exposure is long enough, eventually the electrons that collect in the "bins" in the brightest part of the image will overflow the bin, resulting in blooming. The structure of the CCD allows the electrons to flow more easily in one direction than another, resulting in vertical streaking.

You can see examples of [blooming](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=CCD%20blooming) and [smearing](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=CCD%20smearing) on Google Images. Most appear fairly obvious and extreme, but some are similar to what is seen in your sample image.

Avoid the problem by avoiding high ISOs and long exposures.